# Unable to call button.click() on connectedCallBack() in lightning web component ,it doesn't register

Tags: lightning-web-components, connected-callback, onclickjavascript

I am trying to pass data to a different component, which I was able to achieve with session.Storage but I am not able to click on a button programmatically. Deeply appreciated if anyone can guide me thru it.

****searchBusiness.html****

```
 </template>
    <div class="search-buisness-input-box">
        <lightning-input  class="business-search" name="biz-search" type="text" data-id="biz-search" required value={searchInput}
             onchange={setSearchData} placeholder={label.business_placeholder} onkeyup={checkEnter}
            onblur={handleBlur} >
        </lightning-input>
    </div>
    <div class="search-buisness-btn">
        <button class="slds-button slds-button_stretch secondaryBtn higher" onclick={searchBusiness}>
            {searchButtonText}
        </button>
    </div>
```

****searchBusiness.Js****

```
 connectedCallback() {
        //check if any values were passed in
        if (sessionStorage.getItem('searchText')) {
        this.sessionStorageBusinessSearch = sessionStorage.getItem('searchText');
        this.searchInput = this.sessionStorageBusinessSearch;
        const btn =this.template.querySelector('.secondaryBtn');
        btn?.click();
        sessionStorage.clear();
       
    }
}
```

The btn?.click() doesn't register at all
here is a screen shot of the page. Not sure what I'm doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Any specific reason to use button instead of lightning-button ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend you to check the lifecycle of LWC [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.create_lifecycle_hooks)

`connectedCallback` is not the correct method for querying DOM element since DOM is not rendered when `connectedCallback` is called.

If you `console.log` button in connectedCallback , you will find that your element is null.

I did not understand why a button needs to be clicked when a component is rendered but you can do the same in `renderedCallback`.

If you want to accomplish it, below is the sample code for the same :

```
renderedCallback() {
    const btn =this.template.querySelector('.secondaryBtn');
    console.log("button in renderedCallback :",btn);
        btn?.click();
  }
```

Since `renderedCallback` is called multiple times when a component is re-rendered , you may need to add a flag for executing it only once.

More on lifecycle methods :

- [connectedCallback](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.create_lifecycle_hooks_dom)
- [renderedCallback](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.create_lifecycle_hooks_rendered)